# PromptDialog.Choice does not show choices

Tags: botframework

I'm looking for how we can show choices to user with `IDialog<object>` and `PromtDialog.Choice` method. But the thing is  below code sample doesn't show the choices. Very difficult to find code sample. Looking for a help. Thank you.

```
 List<string> BotOptions = new List<string>();
                BotOptions.Add("Find a Program");
                BotOptions.Add("Find an Event");
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, 
                    ChoiceSelectAsync,BotOptions,
                    "I didn't understand you. I'm cable to help you with", 
                    "Didn't get that", 
                    1, 
                    PromptStyle.None);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the PromptStyle to anything but None.

The available options are:

> Auto
>   Generate buttons for choices and let connector generate the right style based on channel capabilities
>
> AutoText
>   Show choices as Text.
>   The prompt decides if it should generate the text inline or perline based on number of choices.
>
> Inline
>   Show choices on the same line.
>
> PerLine
>   Show choices with one per line.
>
> None
>   Do not show possible choices in the prompt

[source](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/d1/d6a/namespace_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs.html#a8e0b95fd4acd5831ff99c381d8c65beaa06b9281e396db002010bde1de57262eb)

Comment: Thanks for the source and the answer. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

I think to get the prompt of choices you must "call" the promptDialog, use 'PromptChoice' option instead of 'choice'

`var choosenResult = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>
(new string[] { "Find a Program", "Find an Event" },
 "Which one would you like?",
 "Didn't get that", 3);
context.Call(choosenResult, AfterUserHasChosenAsync);`