# PromptDialog Choice with List object Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, botframework

I'm creating a PromptDialog Choice which populates my list of object Options stored in Database. However, it only displayed the type of the Object not the name of the Options. Can anyone suggest me the best way to load Option from database and binding it with the PromptDialog?
Here's what I've tried:

```
    private void ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
    {
        List<Option> ListOptions = Option.CreateListOption();
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, ListOptions, "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?", "Not a valid option", 3);
    }

    private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Option> result)
    {
        try
        {
            Option optionSelected = await result;

            switch (optionSelected.Text)
            {
                case "A":
                    context.Call(new RootDialog(), this.ResumeAfterChoose);
                    break;
                default: { context.Wait(MessageReceiveAsync); break; }
            }
        }
        catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceiveAsync);
        }
    }
```

Here's my Option Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Option()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Text = "";
    }

    public static List<Option> CreateListOption()
    {
        List<Option> list = new List<Option>();
        Option A = new Option();
        A.ID = 1;
        A.Text = "A";
        Option B = new Option();
        B.ID = 2;
        B.Text = "B";
        list.Add(A);
        list.Add(B);
        return list;
    }
}
```

And here's the result I've gotten:
[image: Bot Emulator test result]

Comment: Have you tried what Khushi4.net suggested in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072037/promptdialog-choice-does-not-show-choices ?

Comment: I've read the link you've mentioned before, but my situation here is my list is List of Object. It isn't list of string or any primitive data type.

Comment: Got it, the edit helped a lot. Have you simply tried overriding ToString() of the Option object?

Comment: Wow, voila! That work perfectly. Thank you very much. You've save my idea. But how can it work? Can you explain me about this?

Comment: @Malte And could you create an answer to show the solution clearly in order to help everyone if they are dealing with it like me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding the ToString() method of the Option object solves this.

The Microsoft botframework by default is using PromptStyle.Auto to print the options if you do not provide a PromptStyle as a parameter. So the botframework selects the style depending on the channel. For the emulator it seems to be text so it tries to print the option as a string.

Comment: Many thanks. It seems when we override the ToString() method, the UI will automatically use it to render the text we want to display!

Comment: i am facing the same problem..but i am not able to resolve it can you put sample code for the solution that will be great help ..thanx

Comment: how did you override the ToString() method?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your task by overriding the ToString() method. When **PromptChoice** class tries to throw out the text options from the custom class which was created, it defaults to calling the ToString() method to get the list and render in the Bot Activity.

```
public class Option
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Option()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Text = "";
    }
    public static List<Option> CreateListOption()
    {
        List<Option> list = new List<Option>();
        Option A = new Option();
        A.ID = 1;
        A.Text = "A";
        Option B = new Option();
        B.ID = 2;
        B.Text = "B";
        list.Add(A);
        list.Add(B);
        return list;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some brief explanation would be nice for what you changed in the code and why it solves the problem.

Comment: I just showed how to write the override to ToString as requested above. So when PromtChoice tries to throw out the text options from the custom class which was created, it defaults to calling the ToString to get the text to the options...