# PromptChoiceWithSynonyms for Objects

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to build a bot that leverages the PromptChoiceWithSynonyms. The constructor is this:

```
public PromptOptionsWithSynonyms<T>(
    string prompt, 
    string retry = null, 
    string tooManyAttempts = null, 
    IReadOnlyDictionary<T, IReadOnlyList<T>> choices = null, 
    int attempts = 3, PromptStyler 
    promptStyler = null, 
    IReadOnlyList<string> descriptions = null, 
    string speak = null, 
    string retrySpeak = null, 
    IPromptRecognizer recognizer = null);
```

When using primitive objects, like a string, passing in a

```
IReadOnlyDictionary <string, IReadOnlyList<string>>
```

is pretty simple. When the type T isn't a string, however, and relies on the overriden ToString() to compare between objects, this Dictionary solution makes a little less sense. Is there any way to use this with custom type T that compares a property of T instead? So if T has a property name that is a string, then instead of a

```
 IReadOnlyDictionary<T, IReadOnlyList<T>>
```

choices could still be of type

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>>
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to call PromptChoice.Choice with the PromptOptionsWithSynonyms to let the user choose an object based on a string property of the object

Comment: ToString is not used to compare object, Equals and GetHashCode is used. ToString is used to get an string representation of the object.

Comment: That makes sense. But following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621534/promptdialog-choice-with-list-object-bot-framework and overriding ToString also changed the behavior of PromptChoice for me. Also, I am trying to avoid passing in a List<object> for PromptChoiceWithSynonyms because I want to be to compare the user's input, which is a string, with a number of name synonyms, if that makes sense?

Comment: Right now that is not possible, since there is only 1 generic parameter

Comment: Ah that's too bad. Okay thanks!